# Get frame time in ffmpeg

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I am trying to make a little video player that has seek bar (with ffmpeg, of course). For that i need function that will, using data from frame and/or packet, get me current time in the video that should be set in seek slider.

It should work like this:

```
my_time = get_cur_time()
seek(my_time + 10)
assert(my_time+10 == get_cur_time())
seek(my_time - 10)
assert(my_time-10 == get_cur_time())
```

I do understand that ffmpeg does not support precise seeking, so equality here means "something reasonably close".

What code have i used for this thus far:

```
frame_time = frame->pts * av_q2d(video_dec_ctx->time_base) * 1000;
```

where frame is `AVFrame` and video_dec_ctx is `AVCodecContext`.

And for seeking:

```
int fn = ffmpeg::av_rescale(tsms,fmt_ctx->streams[video_stream->index]->time_base.den,
                            fmt_ctx->streams[video_stream->index]->time_base.num);
int frame = fn / 1000;

printf("\t avformat_seek_file to %d\n",frame);
int flags = AVSEEK_FLAG_FRAME;
if (frame < this->frame->pts)
    flags |= AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD;
if (ffmpeg::av_seek_frame(fmt_ctx, video_stream->index, frame, flags))
{
    printf("\nFailed to seek for time %d",frame);
    return false;
}

avcodec_flush_buffers(video_dec_ctx);
int got_frame = 0;
do
if (av_read_frame(fmt_ctx, &pkt) >= 0) {
    decode_packet_ro(&got_frame, 0);
    av_free_packet(&pkt);
}
else
{
    read_cache = true;
    pkt.data = NULL;
    pkt.size = 0;
    break;
}
while (!(got_frame && this->frame->pts >= frame));
```

The code does forward seeking passably, but after any attempt of backward seeking my second assertion fails. After seeking to previous position, my method of getting time does not return position less that one before seeking. That causes my seek slider to work grossly incorrectly.

Comment: were you able to solve this issue? I am having the same problem.

Comment: I did. Unfortunately, it was some time ago and the code was displaced since.
As far as i remember, it boiled down to using another field of frame structure to get timestamp (and probably using frame numbers instead of time as well)

Answer (score 0):

If it helps someone, I was using `AVStream->time_base` instead of `AVCodecContext->time_base` for calculating the current time (testing my code with **ffmpeg-6.0**).

So the `get_cur_time` method returning current time in milliseconds would be like this:

```
double get_cur_time() {
  double time_ms = (double) currentPTS * av_q2d(audioStream->time_base);
  return time_ms;
}
```

Where `currentPTS` is a global variable saved when a frame is decoded in the sequence

```
av_read_frame(formatContext, audioPacket);
avcodec_send_packet(codecContext, audioPacket);
avcodec_receive_frame(codecContext, audioFrame);
currentPTS = audioFrame->pts;
```

And `audioStream` is an instance of `AVStream`.

And also it's not clear how the original code would update the `this->frame`.
But assuming there's a `avcodec_receive_frame` call in between or other method for the ffmpeg version of that time, maybe the problem was in this part:

```
this->frame->pts >= frame
```

at the end, because it's unidirectional and for backward seeking it would not work as expected.